# How to show the minimal value of $\frac{(a+b)^2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{b^2-4}}$ is 6?

Tags: analysis

I use mathematical analysis to show the minimal value of
$\frac{\left(a + b\right)^{2}}{\,\sqrt{\, a^{2} - 1\,}\, +
\,\sqrt{\, b^{2} - 4\,}\,}\left(a > 1\,,\ b >2\right)$ is $6$, but how to show this only by the math knowledge in high school ?

Comment: What grade? And up till which subject

Comment: sorry i have made a typo!

Comment: @idk Grade 3, any math knowledge of high school can be used.

Comment: @Borntobeproud Think of the geometric interpretation, e.g., distance to a point vs. distance to a line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$f=\frac{(a+b)^2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{b^2-4}}$$ compute the derivatives and simplify to get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{(a+b) \left(2 \sqrt{a^2-1} \sqrt{b^2-4}+a^2-a b-2\right)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}
   \left(\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{b^2-4}\right)^2}\tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=\frac{(a+b) \left(2 \sqrt{a^2-1} \sqrt{b^2-4}-a b+b^2-8\right)}{\sqrt{b^2-4}
   \left(\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{b^2-4}\right)^2}\tag 2$$ and set them equal to $0$. So, we are left with
$$2 \sqrt{a^2-1} \sqrt{b^2-4}+a^2-a b-2=0 \tag 3$$
$$2 \sqrt{a^2-1} \sqrt{b^2-4}-a b+b^2-8=0\tag 4$$ Subtract $(4)$ from $(3)$ to get
$$a^2-b^2+6=0 \implies b=\sqrt{a^2+6}\tag 5$$ Replace in $(3)$ to get
$$a^2-\sqrt{a^2+6} a+2 \sqrt{a^2-1} \sqrt{a^2+2}-2=0 \tag 6$$ Now, tedious multiple squaring would lead to $a=\sqrt 2$ and to the result.

I hope and wish that a simpler solution will appear.

Comment: but the solutions of the equations $$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}=0$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial b}=0$$ must not  automatically lead to the searched Minimum, Maximum or inflection Points are possible.

Comment: How did you conclude that the function will attain the minimum when the partial derivatives are 0. It may be the case that the function might attain it's maximum at this point or they may be inflection points.  I think the bringing out the second partial derivative might sort out things better

Comment: @Manthanein. I totally agree with you. I even do not like the end of my answer with multiple squaring steps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

By AM GM

$$\frac {(a+1)+(a-1)}{2}\gt \sqrt {a^2-1}\Rightarrow a\gt \sqrt {a^2-1}$$
And $$\frac {(b+2)+(b-2)}{2}\gt \sqrt {b^2-4}\Rightarrow b\gt \sqrt {b^2-4}$$

Note that there is no equality because the two terms used can never be equal to each other.

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: @Borntobeproud $a\gt \sqrt {a^2-1}$ and $b\gt \sqrt {b^2-4}$ . Hence $$a+b\gt \sqrt {a^2-1}+\sqrt {b^2-4}\Rightarrow \frac {1}{a+b}\lt \frac {1}{\sqrt {a^2-1}+\sqrt {b^2-4}}$$